# Recurring Paypal Contributions are showing (Pending Incomplete)

Tags: wordpress, paypal, recurring-contributions, pending

We are on Civi 4.7.29 and Wordpress 4.9.4

Today I noticed about 20 transactions with the status Pending Incomplete.  They are all intended to be recurring.   I found out that we are getting notifications from Paypal on everyone of these transactions and some of these people confirmed the payment was a success on their end.  But it is not updating their memberships in Civi and it is not sending them a receipt from civi or recording it as a completed contribution.

Does anyone know where I should start with resolving this?  I did find several other posts related to this issue, but I did not see an answer with any of them.

We confirmed that payments go through properly with no issues, if it's a single/non-recurring payment.

thank you

***Edit****

I just noticed that when trying to make a recurring payment with my credit card instead of paypal I get this error message

DPRP is disabled. DPRP is disabled for this merchant.

Comment: The first thing which comes to my mind is that probably an error or so happens when Paypal sends an update to CiVICRM on the payment status. So I would probably have a look at the log files and see if you can detect such a thing.

Comment: Thank you. I am checking the logs under ConfigandLogs  I am not seeing anything that seem to be related to recurring payments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently Paypal charges extra for recurring functionality and you have not subscribed to the additional $30/mo DPRP service.

> DPRP is disabled. DPRP is disabled for this merchant.

https://www.paypal-community.com/t5/About-Business-Archive/quot-DPRP-is-disabled-for-this-merchant-quot-plz-help/m-p/991717#M14689

In your bounty comment you state:

> I am looking for a solution that will allow us to accept recurring payments through Civi.

In this case I would recommend you look into Stripe.com which provides these options without charging monthly fees. There is a [CiviCRM-Stripe payment extension](https://github.com/drastik/com.drastikbydesign.stripe) in active use and development.

Answer (score 1):

We had a similar problem with Civi on Joomla which was resolved by updating to 4.7.30.

Comment: Thank you. Is this problem a known bug in 4.7.29?

Comment: I just upgraded to 4.7.31 and tried a test transaction.  The exact same issue occurred.

Comment: Did you solve in 4.7.30?